# Attribute error while implementing filter in django manager

Tags: django, pandas, django-models, django-managers

I have a manager in my django project and am implementing a filter as below.
I start the django shell and get this error:

```
>>> from django.http import HttpRequest
>>> r=HttpRequest()
>>> r.session=()
>>> from movierating.models import *
>>> RatingModel.statManager.RatingTimeLine(r)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/data/dashapp/movierating/managers.py", line 27, in RatingTimeLine
(data,display,err)=self.getdatacache(request)
 File "/data/dashapp/movierating/managers.py", line 11, in getdatacache
filterDict=request.session.get('RatingFilter',{})
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
>>> from django.http import HttpRequest
>>> r=HttpRequest()
>>> r.session()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute 'session'r code here
```

The file `manager.py` looks like this:

```
import json,datetime
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import *
from pandas import *
from urllib import urlencode
import hashlib
from django.core.cache import cache
from web.extras import *

class RatingManager(models.Manager):
def getdatacache(self,request):
  filterDict=request.session.get('RatingFilter',{})
  (fapply,display,err)=normalizeFilter(self.model,filterDict)
  cache_id=urlencode(fapply.items())
  cache_id=hashlib.md5('RatingFilter'+cache_id).hexdigest()
  data=None
  if data==None:
     res=self.model.objects.order_by('date').filter(**fapply).values('date').annotate(
        RatingCounts = Count('rating'),
        RatingSum =  Sum('rating'),
     )

     data=DataFrame(list(res))
     data['AverageRating']=data['RatingSum']/data['RatingCounts']
     cache.set(cache_id,data)
  return (data,display,err)

def RatingTimeLine(self,request):
   jsondata={}
   jsondata['chartconfig']={}
   jsondata['chartconfig']['title']="Average Movie Rating per Day"
   jsondata['chartconfig']['names']=['AverageRating']
   (data,display,err)=self.getdatacache(request)
   jsondata['chartconfig']['errors']="<br/>".join(err)
   jsondata['chartconfig']['subtitle']="<br/>".join(display)
   jsondata['series']=data[['data','AverageRating']].values.tolist()
   data=json.dumps(jsondata,cls = SeriesEncoder)
   return {'data':data}
```

I have this model in my `models.py`:

```
class RatingModel(models.Model):
   movie=models.ForeignKey(MovieModel)
   user=models.ForeignKey(userModel)
   rating=models.IntegerField()
   date=models.DateField()
   objects=models.Manager() #default manager
   statManager=RatingManager() #new manager class
   # FilterMapping={
    #'movie':'movie__name', #django relational
    # }
def __unicode__(self):
   return "id: %d rating for movie is %s" %(self.id,self.movie.name) #relationships
class Meta:
   app_label = 'movierating'
   db_table = 'rating'
```

What could be the possible error in this line?

```
filterDict=request.session.get('RatingFilter',{})
```

Answer (score -1):

In your third line you say `r.session=()` - that is, you're assigning an empty tuple to `r.session`. Your code later tries to call `get()` on this tuple, which isn't a supported operation.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. `request.session` is normally filled in by the session middleware. If you're trying to test your code programmatically, you might want to look into the Django testing framework, which [supports sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#testing-tools).